# Remove white space before landscape

Tags: floats, landscape

I am inserting a `landscape` figure.

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/sensor_diffs.jpg}
\caption{Example of a single rep in which sensors are fused together to create a reaction time algorithm}
\label{fig:sensor_diffs}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/sensor_diffs2.jpg}
\caption{Another example of a single rep in which sensors are fused together to create a reaction time algorithm}
\label{fig:sensor_diffs2}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}
```

However, the page before the figure produces lots of white space at the end. There is plenty of text in same section after the figure, however it doesn't seem to be adjusting it properly.

Any ideas?

In addition, I have this issue in several places through the document so any sort of global solution would be ideal.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `afterpage` package for this so that the figures are typeset after filling the current page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\afterpage{%         <--------------like this
  \begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{Example of a single rep in which sensors are fused together to create a reaction time algorithm}
\label{fig:sensor_diffs}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Another example of a single rep in which sensors are fused together to create a reaction time algorithm}
\label{fig:sensor_diffs2}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}
}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sweet this appears to have fixed my issues,. I need to drop to over several more of my figures, but looks like it was the fix.

Comment: @FrankSposaro: No easy automatic solutions for this though.

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly !

Answer (score 7):

I suggest you load the `rotating` package and its `sidewaysfigure` environment, which is a "floating environment" in LaTeX jargon. In contrast, the `landscape` environment is *not* a floating environment, and that's why you're getting the immediate page break when `\begin{landscape}` is encountered.

Observe also that (i) it's possible to have several images, each with its own `\caption` and `\label` statements, in a single `sidewaysfigure` environment, and (ii) the `\centering` instructions don't do anything (and may thus be omitted) since the widths of graphs are set to `\linewidth`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}   % omit 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{rotating}   % for 'sidewaysfigure' environment
\usepackage{lipsum}     % for filler text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]   % filler text

A cross-reference to Figures \ref{fig:sensor_diffs} and \ref{fig:sensor_diffs2}.

\begin{sidewaysfigure}   % this will show up on page 2

\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/sensor_diffs.jpg}
\caption{Example of a single rep in which sensors are fused together to create a reaction time algorithm}
\label{fig:sensor_diffs}

\vspace{2cm}  % get some vertical separation

\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/sensor_diffs2.jpg}
\caption{Another example of a single rep in which sensors are fused together to create a reaction time algorithm}
\label{fig:sensor_diffs2}

\end{sidewaysfigure}

\lipsum[3-7]   % more filler text, continued on page 1 and then on page 3
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is also a really good solution. I will keep this in mind if I start to run into problems with afterpage.

Comment: @Mico How to rotate the page like landcsape

Comment: @DanielValencia - I'm afraid I'm not sure I understand your query/comment. Please clarify what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Mico Sorry if I wasn't clear. When I use sidewaystable, the resulting pdf document appears with the page with the table in vertical orientation. Using sidewaystable, how can I get the page in the pdf rotated as pdflscape package do?

Comment: @DanielValencia - If you want the page in the pdf file to be rotated, you'll have to use the `pdflscape` package and the `landscape` environment. To avoid getting a premature page break, load the `afterpage` package and use something like `\afterpage{\begin{landscape}\begin{table}...\end{table}\end{landscape}}`. (Basically, I'm suggesting you use the solution method advocated in the other answer.)

Comment: Afterpage and all the other things did not work for me. Untill I removed [H] from my figure this did not work eirther! But now it does!